# Oracle Deployment Wizard for .Net error

Tags: .net, oracle, clr

Oracle Deployment Wizard for .Net give me this error during Finish , can any one have any idea about this.

[Directory ORACLECLRDIR does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSsph.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an oracle directory created :

```
SQL> create or replace directory ORACLECLRDIR as '/home/oracle/utl_files';
```

and access rights should be granted at least to your schema(HR) :

```
SQL> grant read, write on directory ORACLECLRDIR to HR;
```